# How to return Promise called value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I call a Promise API for return from ajax. I want to return from then() function like this..
My Ajax funcation:

```
function get_data(url, id) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "/" + id, true);        
    xmlHttp.onerror = reject;
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  });
}
```

Call the ajax function:

```
var class_name = '';
    var url = site_url + "/student/get_classes";
    var id = 2;
    class_name = get_data(url, id).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);//first console
        return result.name;
    });
    console.log(class_name);//second console
```

My Console:
First console: `Object {id: "1", name: "Class One", shift_id: "1", session_id: "1"}`
  Second Console:`Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`
  how to display the [[PromiseValue]] form Promise Object.
Is it posible. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the value from outside a promise, as the value won't be calculated yet. This is because `console.log(class_name)` is called *before* `console.log(result)`, due to node being asynchronous and single threaded. The `get_data` call simply hasn't replied yet, and is going on in the background.

Instead, you should do whatever operations depend on the result *inside* the promise callback, where you currently return `result.name`.